# Option "X Conformance Test Compatibility" for Hummingbird Exceed also available for Xming?

Tags: xming

We are using Hummingbird Exceed (Version 11.0.0.21) so that our users can run a proprietary Solaris 10 X-Application (named Shipplan) on their PC. To make that work we have to enable the "X Conformance Test Compatibility" option in Exceed (`XConfig`). Now we want to migrate to `Xming` (Version 7.5.0.17).

Does anybody know if there is a similar option in `Xming`?
The problem is, that without this option the graphical output is not being refreshed as designated. To enable the `Xtest` extension in `Xming` is not sufficient.